# In file permissions, does the 'others' section not include owner and group owner?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I created a file called `test` and gave it the permissions `----rwxrwx` or `077`. The owner of `test` is a user called `user` and the group owner is root. `user` is not in the group root. The 7 in 07**7** means that all other people can read, write, and execute the file. When I log in as `user`, I can not read, write, or execute `test`.

Also, when I change `test`'s permission to `-rwx---rwx` or `707` and change the owner to root and group owner to `user`, when I log in as `user`, I can not read, write, or execute `test`.

Is this because the 'all other people' section in 07**7** in the permissions do not include the owner or the group owner? Because if it does include the owner and the group owner, wouldn't the owner and the group owner be able to change the file even if their permission as owner or group owner is set to `---` or 0?

Comment: If you set 0xx, you are telling that the owner of the file has no permissions, hence you cant rwx it.

Comment: So even if the file had a 7 in the other users section, the owner still can't rwx it?

Comment: That's quite right.